# Как хранить графики работы?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

Пишу программу вывода графика работы врачей на телевизор. График работы сохраняю в БД. В БД есть Дата начала приема и Дата окончания приема, а также дни недели: Понедельник-Суббота (хранится время приема). Каждый график храню в виде одной строки в таблице.
Возникли вопросы:

1. Как сохранять графики в БД, чтобы потом их по неделям выводить на телевизоре. Например график созданный с 02.11.2020 по 30.11.2020?
2. Как сохранять перекрестные графики (конец ноября-начало декабря) в БД, чтобы потом их по неделям выводить на телевизоре. Например график созданный с 30.11.2020 по 05.12.2020?
   Код пишу на C#. База данных - SQL Server.

Comment: Что вы пробовали, что не получилось, с чем конкретно возникли проблемы?

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Научитесь отличать entity pattern от entity instance. "Дата начала приема и Дата окончания приема, а также время приема с понедельника по субботу." - это pattern. А дата/время конкретных приёмов - это уже instance. И хранятся они в двух разных таблицах (а скорее всего в двух разных наборах таблиц).

Comment: График - это картинка. Его можно сгенерить (даже автоматически) и сохранить. Как картинку показать на экране - надо объяснять? И еще _Этот вопрос в данный момент включает несколько вопросов. Его следует переформулировать, чтобы он был сфокусирован только на одной проблеме._