# Как хранить графики работы врачей в базе данных?

Tags: база-данных

Графики работы храню в БД в одной строке.

В таблице есть поля:

- Дата начала приема, Дата окончания приема - Здесь храню даты
- Понедельник, Вторник, Среда, Четверг, Пятница и Суббота - Здесь храню время приема по дням недели.

Графики могут создавать на 1-2-3 недели, месяц, несколько дней.

Как правильно организовать сохранение графиков в БД?

Хранить графики по неделям, дням или целиком?

Графики за месяц и неделю могу вывести, а вот графики на 2-3 недели и перекрестные графики (например с 30.11.2020 - 05.12.2020) не знаю как вывести.

Подскажите как это реализовать?

Comment: Странный у вас вопрос. Как правильно организовать сохранение графиков в БД - вам решать, ваша же бд. Хранить графики по неделям, дням или целиком - вам решать, ваша же бд. Добавьте в вопрос информацию о используемых программах, пример кода и прочие детали, чтобы люди могли понять, что у вас уже есть и подсказать как это исправить

Comment: Какая СУБД, какой язык/фреймворк, какой уровень владения ими? Если почти никакой, то лучше почитать учебники и посмотреть готовые туториалы в интернете, где разрабатывают какой-нибудь несложный веб-сервис, чтобы потом сделать по аналогии.

Comment: Разделите шаблон графика и график - это разные сущности.

Comment: Аналогичный вопрос с некоторыми другими деталями - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1202505